# How can I install and use PyAutogUI Heroku?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ubuntu, heroku, pyautogui

I already have Python3 selenium script and I used PyAutogUI in this script.
Now, need to deploy to the Heroku server. How can I install PyAutogUI Heroku server?

Comment: ...what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Your code runs on the _server_ and won't be able to drive the GUI on your local machine.

Comment: @Chris Is there some other service that might drive the GUI online as well?

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer, an online service that can take over the mouse and keyboard on your local machine? I hope not. That sounds like a security nightmare.

Comment: No not the local machine rather the machine is like a server but we can configure it. I needed to host a bot for an android game which i would need to run on bluestacks which cannot run online with pyautogui